# IK rigging bones reach out too far

Tags: rigging

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gH5uATTTYB4

I decided to upgrade to IK rigging from usual rigging, and I'm following along until I get to connecting the leg to the bone behind the foot. You'll notice in the video, that their armature remains stationary.

With mine, the leg reaches back to connect to that bone as if they were joined normally (while still moving around as the instructor shows) but when I go to select the pole, the rigging basically snaps the model's knees.

I know there can be slight alterations and movements, but it shouldn't be going out that far. My character does have bones in their toes, so I'm certain that may be influencing it. Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Also due to copyright, and past theft, I am not uploading the model.

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots Sorry but I have already said in my question that due to copyright and past theft, that I will not be uploading or sharing the model.

Comment: you can only share the armature.......